# How to insert data in PostgreSQL using C# with the pascalcase to lowercase

Tags: c#, asp.net, postgresql, c#-4.0, pgadmin

I have a model for performing bulk insert operation in PostgreSQL, I am following the PascalCase for my fields In the model as we follow, and most of the code is implemented. But when we get the Hosted DB we are unable to perform the insert operation because all the columns are in lowercase.
And the error is `sequence contains no matching element`

So, for testing, I changed the one model field in lowercase, and records are inserted successfully.

So I just want to know is there any way not to change every field in models and different places,
Just write some code in the context file or using the model builder class and all the fields will convert into the lowercase when we insert the records in PostgreSQL.

```
public class ApplicationStarted
    {
     public int ApplicationStartedRecord { get; set; }
     public DateTime? ApplicationCreatedDate { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Please post sample code where you are inserting a record

Comment: I'm using the NpgsqlBulkUploader for the bulk inset 
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql.Bulk/#